# Vector correcting

Tags: qgis-plugins

I use QGIS 2.14. In fact I made wells (more than 100 holes) in a field. I took the coordinates with the DGPS that I exported to QGIS, but afterwards we went to the field to checked some coordinates with the RTK but not all the hole, just to check if the coordinates taken with the DGPS corresponded to the RTK.Unfortunately this was not the case. The problem is that in QGIS the coordinates of the points taken with the DGPS are offset from the RTK and I would like to correct them . The problem is that I have just some coordinates taken with the RTK and I wish to use that in order to correct the coordinates of the holes taken by the DGPS.  I do not know if there is a method to do it.

Comment: Look for a conflation tool, maybe.